# Convert list of tuple with string and list to the list of lists. [('str', [0, 0])...] to [['str', 0, 0]...]

Tags: python, list, tuples

Can somebody help me convert list like this:

```
list1 = [('Monday', [1, 2]), ('Tuesday', [3, 4])]
```

to the list like that:

```
list2 = [['Monday', 1, 2], ['Tuesday', 3, 4]
```

Any help will be appretiated.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [('Monday', [1, 2]), ('Tuesday', [3, 4])]
list2 = [[e[0], *e[1]] for e in list1]
print(list2)
```

prints

```
[['Monday', 1, 2], ['Tuesday', 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is fixed, use unpacking:

```
list1 = [('Monday', [1, 2]), ('Tuesday', [3, 4])]

list2 = [[a, *b] for a, b in list1]
```

output: `[['Monday', 1, 2], ['Tuesday', 3, 4]]`